# is it possible to format tooltips in bokeh to include text after the value in the column? eg: add 'tonnes' or 'cm' after each value

Tags: python, text, format, tooltip, bokeh

I want the units of horsepower ('HP') and Weight ('tonnes') to show when I hover over each point.
As of now, it just shows the values (image attached).
I want it to show, for instance:
Model: plymouth fury
Weight: 3785 **tonnes**
HP: 95 **HP**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7k5K.png

Here is my code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook,show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource as cds

output_notebook()
import seaborn as sns

mpg = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
mpg.head()

usa = mpg[mpg.origin == 'usa']
japan = mpg[mpg.origin == 'japan']
europe = mpg[mpg.origin == 'europe']

sourceU = cds(data=usa)
sourceJ = cds(data=japan)
sourceE = cds(data=europe)

tt = [('Model','@name'),('Weight','@weight'),('HP','@horsepower')]
#Is there a way to modify this line above to include the unit as an additional string after the column value?


fig1 = figure(x_axis_label = 'Weight',y_axis_label='HP',width=350,height=300,title="USA",tooltips=tt)
fig2 = figure(x_axis_label = 'Weight',y_axis_label='HP',width=350,height=300,title="Japan",tooltips=tt)
fig3 = figure(x_axis_label = 'Weight',y_axis_label='HP',width=350,height=300,title="Europe",tooltips=tt)

fig1.circle(x='weight',y='horsepower',source=sourceU)
fig2.circle(x='weight',y='horsepower',source=sourceJ)
fig3.circle(x='weight',y='horsepower',source=sourceE)

show(row(fig1,fig2,fig3))
```

Comment: You can put whatever string you want in the second string in each tuple: `('Weight','@weight lbs')`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this flexible solution, that enables to use html and change color, font etc:

```
tt = f"""<b>The Model is </b> @name <br>
         <b>@weight</b> Tonnes (Weight) <br>
         <b>HP is </b> <font color="green">@horsepower HP</font> <br>
         """
```